# Swift 3 Xcode: How to display battery levels as an integer?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, string-formatting

I am making an app to read battery percentage using Swift!
Right now my out is something like this:
61.0% or 24.0% or 89.0%
What I'm trying to fix is getting rid of the .0 so it's an Int.
This is my code so far:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var infoLabel: UILabel!

var batteryLevel: Float {
    return UIDevice.current.batteryLevel
}

var timer = Timer()

func scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(){
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60, target: self, selector: #selector(self.someFunction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func someFunction() {
    self.infoLabel.text = "\(batteryLevel * 100)%"
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
    someFunction()
    scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

}
```

I have tried something like this:

```
var realBatteryLevel = Int(batteryLevel)
```

However, I get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6B471.png)

I have tried other method but none with any luck. Please, any solutions would be awesome! Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I was considering making the float `batteryLevel` into a String and then replacing ".0" with "" and I have seen this somewhere, however, I'm not sure how!

Comment: Perform the integer conversion in `someFunction` or declare `realBatteryLevel` as a computed variable

Comment: @Paulw11 Unfortunately for whatever reason both of those methods do not cause an error however they both make my output 0%

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
func someFunction() {
    self.infoLabel.text = String(format: "%.0f%%", batteryLevel * 100)
}
```

For future reference, all *string format specifiers* are [listed here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html).

Comment: Thanks this worked PERFECTLY. Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

You just need to convert It inside your function :

```
func someFunction() {
self.infoLabel.text = "\(Int(batteryLevel * 100))%" }
```

Comment: The `batteryLevel` is a normalized value (i.e, between `0.0` and `1.0`). As such, `Int(batteryLevel)` expression will be *zero* most of the time.

Comment: As @PauloMattos said and I said in a previous comment this just makes my output equal to 0% everytime. Thanks for trying

Comment: I've edited my answer, try `Int(batteryLevel * 100)`

Comment: @AshXVI @MattPidd Much better! Not trying to be pickcy here, but still looses the decimal precision since no *rounding* is performed (i.e, the decimal digits are simply *discarded* by the given `Int` initializer). The `String(format:)` based solution, by yours truly, doesn't have this issue ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Alternately, you could create an Int computed property for `batteryLevel`:

```
var batteryLevel: Int {
  return Int(round(UIDevice.current.batteryLevel * 100))
}
```

Note that you might not be able to get the battery level. You should test for that and display a different string:

```
if UIDevice.current.batteryState == .unknown {
  self.batteryLevelLabel.text = "n/a"
} else {
  self.batteryLevelLabel.text = "\(self.batteryLevel)%"
}
```

Also note that rather than running a timer to fetch the battery level, you should subscribe to the `.UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChange` notification. The "meat" of a view controller that handles all of this might look as follows:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var batteryLevelLabel: UILabel!

  ///Holds the notification handler for battery notifications.
  var batteryNotificationHandler: Any?

  ///A computed property that returns the battery level as an int, using rounding.
  var batteryLevel: Int {
    return Int(round(UIDevice.current.batteryLevel * 100))
  }

  ///A function to display the current battery level to a label, 
  ////or the string "n/a" if the battery level can't be determined.
  func showBatteryLevel() {
    if UIDevice.current.batteryState == .unknown {
      self.batteryLevelLabel.text = "n/a"

    } else {
      self.batteryLevelLabel.text = "\(self.batteryLevel)%"
    }
  }

  override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    ///If we have a battery level observer, remove it since we're about to disappear
    if let observer = batteryNotificationHandler {
      NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer: observer)
    }
  }
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    showBatteryLevel() //display the battery level once as soon as we appear

    //Create a notifiation handler for .UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChange 
    //notifications that calls showBatteryLevel()
    batteryNotificationHandler =
      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChange,
                                             object: nil,
                                             queue: nil, using: {
                                              (Notification) in
                                              self.showBatteryLevel()
    })
  }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      //Tell UIDevice that we want battery level notifications
      UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
  }
}
```

Comment: As somebody pointed out in a now-deleted comment, it would really be better to add observers for both the `.UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChange` notification **and** the `.UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChange` notification, so you can tell when you are going to get battery level notifications and you wouldn't need to check the UIDevice.current.batteryState each time before trying to read the battery state.